# PreferenceActivity with TextItems

Tags: android, preferences, listactivity, preferenceactivity

I'd like to use `PreferenceActivity` for my games settings. But I'd like to add to that list, so that after the settings items in the list, there would be just text items like "MyGame, version 0.1" or clickable text item "Rate my app" etc.

What's the "correct" or most straighforward way of doing this? I know I can specify a custom layout xml with ListView in it and populate that with the preferences but I'd like to have my custom (clickable) text items in that ListView too, or atleast appear like they were in that list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I tried to tell was that I needed what is shown as "Costum Preference" [sic] in this picture:

[image: custom preference]
<sub>(source: [kaloer.com](http://www.kaloer.com/sites/default/files/custompref.png))</sub>

You can create it just by using

```
<Preference
    android:title="Custom Preference"
    android:summary="This works almost like a button"
    android:key="customPref" />
```

This example I found from: http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Comment: It is default preference. If you use UI in Eclipse, select parent preference (e.g: `PreferenceCategory`), click button `Add`, you can see some default preferences...

Answer (score 0):

To put all setting to below XML file after that file use in the activity all setting are display in list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:example="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.uks.android.frsad.common">

<EditTextPreference android:title="Server URL"
        android:dialogTitle="Server URL Path" android:dialogMessage="Path of Web Server"
        android:key="server_url_path" android:summary="Sets the Server URL Path for WebService." />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I think you entirely missed the question? I'm using exactly that already, but that xml (afaik) doens't allow me to add just text items (not editable, just pure text in a list).

Comment: <PreferenceCategory android:title="Other Prefernces"> use this one please see bbelow link  http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/android-preferences/